# In Firefox, localStorage data is not accessible by different windows in the same local domain. Is there a workaround?

Tags: firefox, local-storage

In JavaScript, I wrote data to localStorage from file:///D:/Path/window1.html.

I used a link to open a window file in the same domain - ///D:/Path/window2.html.

The localStorage data in window2 should be the same as window1, but it isn't. This works correctly in Chrome. Is there some workaround? This is Firefox 103.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was previously [reported](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1730419) and won't be fixed because that would create a security issue. It may not work in the future in other browsers. Serving the pages from a local server is suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I posted a close related question today.
My 'workaround' for Firefox is to open window1.html and window2.html not  directly as they are, but copy them to window3.html, and then open that file in Firefox.
Do this with your 2 files one after another, and you can access the localstorage-data from both browser-windows simultaneously.